# Android development - Search interface with sqlite, listview, edittext and a button

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, filter, android-edittext

I'm new to android development and I really need some help.

I just want to do a query in my Sqlite database based in an EditText input and short the results in a Listview, after the "search" button is pressed.

I've finished with the errors, but the listview just don't show up when the button is pressed.

Here is my code:

```
btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {   
            //Here is my SimpleCursorAdapter; 
            dataSource = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.consulta_grupos_lihas, helper.Busca(someString), campos, new int[] {R.ConsultaGruposLinhas.txvCodigo, R.ConsultaGruposLinhas.txvDescricao});
            //And so i set the Adapter
            listview.setAdapter(dataSource); 
        }
    });
```

And so the helper.Busca(someString) (in my database class) is the way I use to make the query

```
public Cursor Busca (String search) {
    String sql = "grup_descricao LIKE '% "+ search +" %'";
    return this.mDb.query("grupos", new String [] {"_id", "grup_descricao", "grup_datacad"}, sql, null, null, null, null);
}
```

I'd really appreciate if someone can help me. Thanks very much for the attention.

Comment: and R.layout.consulta_grupos_lihas while you're at it. Have you gotten this to display at all when setting sql to null?

Comment: No, but good idea. Thaks for the help Pork. Besides, I've realized that it was a sql syntax error. I was using the LIKE statement, and it was something like this: "LIKE '%' something '%'". But when I removed the spaces around "something", the shit worked. Thanks again for your comment. Have a good day ^^.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized that it was a sql syntax error. I was using the LIKE statement, and it was something like this: "LIKE '%' something '%'". But when I removed the spaces around "something", it just worked!